# Embedding of products of projective spaces into a projective space

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology

Does anybody know estimates on the minimal dimension $k$ for which the product $P^n \times P^m$ can be smoothly embedded into $P^k$? I am interested in projective spaces over $\mathbb RR$ and $\mathbb C$.

Matthias Kreck

Comment: The Segre embedding shows $k \leq (n+1)(m+1)-1$.

Comment: The Whitney embedding theorem gives $k\leq 2(n+m)$ for real projective spaces. This can be improved by $1$ if $n$ and $m$ are powers of two, see the paper "Embeddings in Euclidean space" by Schwarzenberger. This may not be optimal for embeddings into projective space, though.

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer, but too long for a comment:

For embeddings of $\mathbb RP^m \times \mathbb RP^n$ not into $\mathbb RP^k$ but into Euclidian space, references include:

> *Vector fields on $\mathbb RP^m \times \mathbb RP^n$* by Donald M. Davis, [Proc. Amer. Math. Soc.](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2012-140-12/S0002-9939-2012-11282-1/), 2012

and

> *Note on $\gamma$-dimension and products of real projective spaces* by Teiichi Kobayashi, [J. Math. Soc. Japan](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jmsj/1239801521), 1982

In the latter it is proved that the dimension of the normal bundle of $\mathbb RP^m \times \mathbb RP^n$ is at least 
[image: max]

For products of more than two factors see

> *On the Nonimmersion of Products of Real Projective Spaces* by Hyun-Jong Song and W. Stephen Wilson, [Trans. Amer. Math. Soc](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2001241), 1990